# Assigning arrays to array

Tags: arrays, c, clang

If an already existing array with elements is assigned to an empty array variable using '=', are they connected?

For instance `char x[] = "ABC";` is the existing array and if I make new array `char new[];` and do `char new[] = char x[];` does changing one array effect another?

Comment: Hint: `strcpy` if you're manipulating C character strings. This is different from generic *arrays*. Also keep in mind some array definitions decay to pointers, so this isn't copying data, it's copying the pointer.

Comment: `empty array variable` What is an _empty array variable_? `char new[];` will not compile and `char new[] = char x[];` will also not compile.

Comment: @KamilCuk `char new[]; will not compile`: that depends on the context. It will compile if it is a file scope declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char x[] = "ABC";` is the initialisation of the `x` array and it is the only example where the string literal is being copied.

`char new[] = char x[];` does nothing as it is invalid syntax and the program will not compile at all.

`char new[] = x;` is illegal as you cannot initialize array with other array.

```
char new[4];
new = x;
```

is illegal because you cant assign the arrays.

you need to:

```
char new[4];
strcpy(new,x);
```

or

```
memcpy(new,x,szieof(new));
```